# React Kendo Grid resize height dynamically

Tags: kendo-react-ui

React Kendo grid once data assigned to the grid I need to resize the gird based on available space, and exclude header and footer of page

Answer (score 0):

The height can be set using the styles as regular HTML. To exclude the headers and footers you can use [calc method](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp). For example:

```
height: "calc(100% - 150px)"
```